# How do I do cardlayout with processing?

Tags: java, jpanel, processing, cardlayout

I want to do a game where I have to switch screens.  I have Jbuttons put on the JPanels, and when you click a button it switches the panel.  However, I have only done this with regular graphics.
Here is an example with processing but I don't really understand what is going on:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;

public class Main {

private JFrame window;

private JPanel cardPanel;

private OptionPanel panel1;    
private DrawingSurface panel2;

private PSurfaceAWT.SmoothCanvas processingCanvas;

public Main() {
    panel2 = new DrawingSurface();
    panel2.runMe();

    PSurfaceAWT surf = (PSurfaceAWT) panel2.getSurface();
    processingCanvas = (PSurfaceAWT.SmoothCanvas) surf.getNative();
    window = (JFrame)processingCanvas.getFrame();

    window.setBounds(0,0,800, 600);
    window.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setResizable(true);

    cardPanel = new JPanel();
    CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
    cardPanel.setLayout(cl);

    window.getContentPane().removeAll();

    panel1 = new OptionPanel(this);    
    panel2 = new DrawingSurface();

    cardPanel.add(panel1,"1");
    cardPanel.add(processingCanvas,"2");

    window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    window.add(cardPanel);
    window.revalidate();
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Main m = new Main();
}

public void changePanel() {
    ((CardLayout)cardPanel.getLayout()).next(cardPanel);
    processingCanvas.requestFocus();
}

}
```

The optionpanel is this(main is above):

```
public class OptionPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

Main w;

public OptionPanel(Main w) {
    this.w = w;
    JButton button = new JButton("Press me!");
    button.addActionListener(this);
    add(button);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    w.changePanel();
}

}
```

This example has a drawing surface where it draws a mario and it jumps on some rectangles. I just want to know how to connect the different panels and be able to draw an each panel.

Answer (score 0):

You generally shouldn't mix Swing and Processing like this.

Specifically, you can embed Processing in Swing, but you shouldn't try to embed Swing inside Processing. Processing has its own rendering thread and its own event queue, which makes it very hard to put Swing inside Processing.

Even embedding Processing in Swing was made much more complicated in Processing 3, so that should also be avoided if at all possible.

So honestly, if I were you, I would try to rethink my approach. Can you do this with two separate windows? Maybe a Swing JFrame that shows buttons, and then a separate Processing window that shows the sketch? Maybe you can hide one and show the other at the same time?

If you really really need to mix Swing and Processing, then you need to put the Processing sketch inside the Swing window instead of trying to put Swing component inside the Processing window. The Processing window is technically a JFrame, but you should probably not be messing with it like that. Instead, get the `processingCanvas` and add it to your own JFrame.